# Get single image from nest-camera

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access

Using the new Device Access for Google Nest Cameras there is a [trait](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-image) available to get an image from the camera - however the question is, how you can get the download-url for a non-event-based image?

I've tried:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/project-id/devices/device-id:executeCommand' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer access-token' \
  --data-raw '{
    "command" : "sdm.devices.commands.CameraImage",
    "params" : {}
  }'
```

Which is unfortunately not working

Comment: so far i've never seen that CameraImage field populated. Just CameraEventImage.

Answer (score 3):

It only shows the supported resolution.
Currently you can only get a snapshot from an event.

I got it working, but it's a bit too slow for my use-case: 'downloading a snapshot for a push-notification when someone rings my (classic) doorbell'

[edit]

I have a workaround by grabbing a single frame of the RTSP stream:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel fatal -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsps://stream-eu1-delta.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/... -frames:v 2 -r 1 -s 1920x1280 snapshot.jpg
```

delay 2-5 seconds.